# How do OrientDB edges compare to the relational DB paradigm?

Tags: relational-database, graph-theory, orientdb, graph-databases

I am new to graph databases so excuse me if I ask too basic things.

In a relational database, relations are made between fields of the tables. It makes sense because when we want to show records from two tables, we make a join and print record.

But in case of OrientDB, we make edges - so does it need to be created record to record, instead of field to field as in an RDBMS?

Comment: "In a relational database, relations are made between fields of the tables." No, in a relational DB a table, aka relation in the sense of a set of rows/tuples, represents a relation in the sense of a relationship/association. Hence "relational". "relations between fields of the tables" are FKs & are for integrity & not for recording or querying data. This question is too broad & it is a duplicate & it is unresearched. See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 4):

OrientDB manages relations as physical links to records, assigned only once when the edge is created.
OrientDB not use JOIN. Instead, use the links that has a relationship managed by storing the RID target in the record source. It 'very similar to store a pointer between two objects in memory.
An edge connects two vertices and must have: a unique identifier, links vertex incoming, outgoing link vertex and label that defines the type of connection.

This is a little example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but if I have a million records, how would I do it? Linking a million records, one by one?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding graph databases in general, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database and books such as
[Graph Databases](http://graphdatabases.com/).

On the relationship between Relational and Graph databases, I think you might find it useful to remember that there are fundamentally two types of "relational tables":

1. those in which each row represents an entity;
2. those in which each row represents a relationship between entities.

If this distinction holds in a database schema, then the rows representing entities correspond closely to "Vertices" in Graph Database terminology, and the rows representing relationships between entities correspond to "Edges" in Graph Database terminology.

It follows that if you want to transfer (to a graph database) the information in a relational table, T1, and if each row of T1 represents an entity, and if T1 has no foreign keys, you might not need any "outgoing" edges from that table.  If another table refers to the entities represented by the rows of T1, then those references would correspond to "incoming" edges relative to T1.

Of course, the task of transferring the information to another DBMS might also be a good time to re-design the database schema.  The general topic of database design is covered in texts such as the one mentioned above.

Comment: That entity-vs-relationship table "fundamental difference" is from the ER model, not the relational model. In the relational model all tables/relations represent relation(ship)s/associations & for every superkey in every table (base or query result) its values in that table identify some (possibly associative) entity type. (Also, in the ER model a row represents an entity or a relationship instance, and every relationship instance identifies an associative entity.)